# Unity shader: syntax error: unexpected token '(' at line 70 (on d3d11) help!!!! shader noob

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader

> undeclared identifier 'sphereHit' at line 82 (on d3d11)

(shader noob sorry) I need some help figuring out these errors, thanks...

```
Shader "Unlit/VolSDFOne"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}

    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100



        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            // make fog work
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;

                float4 pos : SV_POSITION; // Clip space
                float3 wPos : TEXCOORD1; // World position
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.wPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz; 
                return o;
            }

            float3 _Centre;
            float _Radius;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                // apply fog
                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                return col;

                float3 worldPosition = i.wPos;
                float3 viewDirection = normalize(i.wPos - _WorldSpaceCameraPos);


                bool sphereHit (float3 p)
                {
                    return distance(p,_Centre) < _Radius;
                }

                #define STEP_SIZE 0.01
                #define STEPS 35

                bool raymarchHit (float3 position, float3 direction)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < STEPS; i++)
                    {
                        if ( sphereHit(position) )
                            return true;
                            position += direction * STEP_SIZE;
                    }

                    return false;
                }

                if ( raymarchHit(worldPosition, viewDirection) )
                    return fixed4(1,0,0,1); // Red if hit the ball
                else
                    return fixed4(1,1,1,1); // White otherwise
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a bit more effort into your questions. Don't put unnecessary info in the title like your experience or a callout for help, and dont fill your question with a lot of a's to get to the minimum amount of characters for a question. You could have used that space to tell us what you tried so far.

Comment: Start by e.g. at least tell us which line is 82 .. nobody wants to count them ...

Comment: Sorry, I was quite frustrated

Answer (score 0):

You are defining functions in a piece of the shader that is executed linearly. move the function definitions outside of the scope of the fixed4 frag function and it should work.

```
Shader "Unlit/VolSDFOne" { Properties { _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
}
SubShader
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 100



    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        // make fog work
        #pragma multi_compile_fog

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;

            float4 pos : SV_POSITION; // Clip space
            float3 wPos : TEXCOORD1; // World position
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.wPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz; 
            return o;
        }

        float3 _Centre;
        float _Radius;

        float3 worldPosition = i.wPos;
        float3 viewDirection = normalize(i.wPos - _WorldSpaceCameraPos);


        bool sphereHit (float3 p)
        {
            return distance(p,_Centre) < _Radius;
        }

        #define STEP_SIZE 0.01
        #define STEPS 35

        bool raymarchHit (float3 position, float3 direction)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < STEPS; i++)
            {
                if ( sphereHit(position) )
                    return true;
                    position += direction * STEP_SIZE;
            }
            return false;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            // sample the texture
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            // apply fog
            UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
            //return col;

            if ( raymarchHit(worldPosition, viewDirection) )
                return fixed4(1,0,0,1); // Red if hit the ball
            else
                return fixed4(1,1,1,1); // White otherwise
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

now this code might still have some errors but should help you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks so much, now I just get this... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end at line 88 do you know what could be causing it?

Comment: it might be that you dont need the ENDCG line at all, but im not sure. try removing it or placing it 1 } lower to check if its in the right scope

Comment: If you this works, please edit my answer to reflect what made it work. that way other people that might stumble upon this question can try and use the answer as well. If it doesnt work, please give me some info on whats on the line that gives the error, so that I dont have to go copy paste everything into an editor to help with line counting. What @derHugo said: nobody likes counting lines and guessing if you had any whitelines above it that skewed the count